# Querying Neptune using Athena - Neptune connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to query my Neptune cluster from Athena using the Athena Neptune connector.

The queries for node table work fine but when i try to query the Edge tables i'm facing issues.

Eg:`SELECT * FROM "database"."hasasset" WHERE out = '38957409_R8' limit 10;`
Queries like this, where i'm trying to filter by `in` or `out`  return no results while i know for a fact that there are multiple entries with `out`  value that i'm trying to match with.

I can see this through a query like `SELECT * FROM "database"."hasasset" limit 10;`  which shows me the rows with those out values.

I tried querying other edge tables and see the same issue. I was expecting to be able to filter by in or out value and retrieve records as if they were any other property. I verified that the datatype for these columns is string and i'm using the right values

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing this out.

It's a defect, tracking here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/issues/1138

No current workaround